# What is the difference between "none" and "white" on package pagecolor?

Tags: color, backgrounds, pagecolor

The title pretty much says it all. [`pagecolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pagecolor) seems to treat the options `white` and `none` differently, in particular because `none` doesn't work with package [`crop`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/crop). What would be the reasons to use `none` instead of `white` and vice-versa? Will any of them lead to a larger pdf or to differences when printing?

Comment: print your document on black paper, you will see a difference

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Are there printers that can print white ink?  Mixing cyan magenta and yellow on an inkjet is basically the same as black.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Description

- `pagecolor=none` is the default, and it means, there is no background (can be thought of as transparent background)
- `pagecolor=white` explicitly sets the background color to `white`

You can see the difference, if you insert the resulting PDFs to another document, with a non-standard background color.
In the example below, I inserted `pagecolor_white.pdf` and `pagecolor_none.pdf` to a document with yellow background.

A normal use case for this are beamer presentations with a background color other than white, where you want to insert PDFs with transparent background or explicitly need the white background.

Regarding the file size, it can be expected, that a PDF with specific background color is minimal but negligibly (~ 1 KB) larger than a PDF with `pagecolor=none` (or without the `pagecolor` package).

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

##### `pagecolor_white.tex`

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[pagecolor=white]{pagecolor}

\begin{document}
    \huge\verb|pagecolor=white|
\end{document}
```

##### `pagecolor_none.tex`

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[pagecolor=none]{pagecolor} % As `none` is the default, you don't realy need this package here.

\begin{document}
    \huge\verb|pagecolor=none|
\end{document}
```

##### `pagecolor.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pagecolor=yellow]{pagecolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=20mm]{pagecolor_white}

\includegraphics[height=20mm]{pagecolor_none}
\end{document}
```